# command line MSBuild works - remote build produces errors

Tags: msbuild, command-prompt, cobol

I am setting up a process to build remotely a suite of COBOL programs.  A virtual machine has Visual Studio 2017 installed along with a Micro Focus COBOL Enterprise Developer 4.0 Visual Studio 2017 plugin.  The programs use CICS as their UI and work with a Microsoft SQL Server backend.  Opening a developer command prompt in Visual Studio and issuing a MSBuild command with the solution as the parameter successfully builds the programs.  A remote build does not - the error is
MSBUILD : error MSB4025: The project file could not be loaded. Root element is missing.
any ideas?

Comment: Might be using another msbuild version. But what does 'remote build' entail?

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the "Micro Focus Enterprise Developer Build tools" on the CI machine.